# React Native Flat list Column

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Basically, my flatlist is in 2 columns. But if there is an odd number of item the last row will be stretch.

This is my Flatlist coding

```
export default class Cluster1 extends Component{
render(){
    const getClusterByName = (name) => 
Cluster.find(cluster => cluster.hasOwnProperty(name))[name]
    return(
        <ScrollView>
        <FlatList
        numColumns= {2}
        data={getClusterByName('cluster1')}
        renderItem={({item,index})=>{
            return(
                <FlatListItem  item={item} index={index}>

                </FlatListItem>);
        }}
        >
        </FlatList>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
```

Then this is my FlatlistItem

```
class FlatListItem extends Component{
render(){
    const {itemWidth} = this.props
    return(
        <View style={styles.list}>
        <View>


        <Text style={styles.itemText}>{this.props.item.name}</Text>

        </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

style code

```
   const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
    list:{
    flex:1,
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    width: 50,
    padding:20,
    backgroundColor: 'ghostwhite',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    margin: 2,


    }
```

This will be the output as you can see the 'f' is stretch. I want it make the same width
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03i0R.png)

Comment: Add your `styles.list` code

Comment: oh yeah i forgot about it my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `flex: 1` from your `styles.list` as that would cause it to occupy the entire width.

If you want them to occupy half the width then you can change it to `flex: 0.5` or the `width` style to `Dimensions.get('window').width / 2`.

Answer (score 1):

set width to your `renderItem` as `Dimensions.get('window').width  / 2;`

Use this :

```
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    width: (Dimensions.get('window').width - 4 * 10) / 2,
    padding:20,
    backgroundColor: 'ghostwhite',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    margin: 2,
```